# iOS 8 Core Data Issue: global ID may not be temporary when recording

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios8, xcode6

I'm migrating my App from iOS 7 to iOS 8, and I've been receiving the following error in Xcode when I try to save the Core Data context. This error was not present in iOS 7 and Xcode 5.

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
[_managedObjectContext save:&error]
```

This is the exception:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'recordChangeSnapshot:forObjectID:: global ID may not be temporary when recording

Here's the code for my managedObjectContext:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {    
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext; 
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil) {
        NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

        [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
            [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:coordinator];
        }];

        _managedObjectContext = moc;
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"Merging in changes from iCloud...");

    NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [self managedObjectContext];

    [moc performBlock:^{

        [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

        NSNotification* refreshNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"SomethingChanged"
                                                                        object:self
                                                                      userInfo:[notification userInfo]];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:refreshNotification];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Are you using thread confinement (-[NSManagedObjectContext init]) or queue confinement with nested contexts (-[NSManagedObjectContext initWithConcurrencyType:]) ? And what type of persistent store are you using?

Comment: @quellish See above the code for my managedObjectContext. Do you think this is an issue with trying to use Core Data with iCloud?

Comment: It may be, but it's MUCH more likely to be because of your use of `performBlockAndWait:`. That method does *not* process user events, which can leave Core Data in an unexpected state. Permanent IDs are assigned by the persistent store as part of a save. If user events were not processed.... bad stuff can happen. http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/93355099502/performblock-vs-performblockandwait

Comment: You should also not use `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` when using nested contexts. Nested contexts obsolete this method of propagating changes. https://vimeo.com/101448932

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I think the issue was that my NSManagedObject had an initWithCoder method due to a legacy key-value store. Once I got rid of that, I did not have any more issues. I appreciate the suggestions below as well!

Comment: Yup, NSCoding would cause all kinds of bizarre problems.