# iOS 8 CoreData Issue 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'recordChangeSnapshot:forObjectID:: global ID may not be temporary when recording'

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios8

I am having real difficulties resolving this issue when migrating my App from iOS7 to iOS8, the app works perfect on iOS7.

It crashes when I am trying to save

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {  <---- crashes here
     NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
 }
```

I've seen only 2 similar issues on stackoverflow but none of the responses were relevant to my problem.

[iOS 8 CoreData Issue: recordChangeSnapshot:forObjectID:: global ID may not be temporary when recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459715/ios-8-coredata-issue-recordchangesnapshotforobjectid-global-id-may-not-be-te)

[iOS 8 Core Data Issue: global ID may not be temporary when recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819679/ios-8-core-data-issue-global-id-may-not-be-temporary-when-recording)

Its not easy to post all the code. I don't know where to begin debugging !, some help please. Thanks

Comment: Looks like I am going to change my whole core data ORM to ActiveRecord just to avoid this problem. hmmmmm

Answer (score 10):

Is this call to `[managedObjectContext save:&error]` happening on a background thread? Is it usually called on the main thread?

> The pattern recommended for concurrent programming with Core Data is thread confinement: each thread must have its own entirely private managed object context.

When working with your Core Data code, you can use `isMainThread` to determine if you're on a background thread and switch to the main thread prior to working with Core Data:

```
- (void)yourCoreDataTask {
    if (![[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self yourCoreDataTask];
        });
        return;
    }

    // Now on the Main Thread. Work with Core Data safely.
}
```